# Calculating Jaccard distance of a large matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, similarity, large-data

I have a large matrix of size 40K * 900K. It is a sparse, binary matrix and I would like to calculate the Jaccard distance between its rows (40K by 40K Jacard distance in total). I'm aware of built-in function `pdist` which calculates ths similarity for me, but due to matrix size it seems like it can't and it shows me the following error message.

```
 Matrix is too large to convert to linear index.

 Error in ==> pdist at 139
     elseif any(imag(X(:)))
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The result would be a non-sparse matrix, which takes up about 12 GB of memory. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: I should find the Jaccard similarity between different items. Is there any other efficient way to do that ?

Comment: My comment was not about efficiency of implementation, but whether you will actually be able to use the result. What are you going to do with that 40k x 40k matrix once you have it?